# Can we SSH to Windows EC2 instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am new to AWS and I have created a new Windows EC2 instance. I see ways to SSH to different instances like Amazon Linux, Ubuntu using PuTTY. But not for Windows instance. Can we not connect to Windows instance using PuTTY? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you've installed and correctly configured an SSH server on your Windows instance, added the relevant SSH public key(s), and configured the relevant firewalls (AWS Security Groups plus the Windows Firewall) correctly. Typically, however, you'd use Remote Desktop (RDP) to connect to a Windows EC2 instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell_Protocol) to [Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) and [Mac](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-mac-instances.html) instance on AWS. You can use [Remote Desktop (RDP) to access Windows Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html).

Suppose you wanted to SSH into a Windows instance, then you would have to install [OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server). Which would still require access to the Windows instance.

AWS offers a few ways to access your Windows instance, one of them is AWS Systems Manager Session Manager (SSM). You would need to enable RDP through SSM. You can find out how to do this via this [workshop](https://reinvent2019.aws-management.tools/mgt406/en/optional/step7.html). Alternatively configure [SSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html) to run powershell commands against the instance **Note** the instance must have a role that has IAM access to SSM. If the instance is in a private VPC it would require access to SSM via [endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html).

If your instances is in a public subnet, and has a public IP address then you can easily connect to your Windows instance using RDP. **Note** just like your EC2 Instances running Linux, the security group must allow access. In this case it must be to RDP (3389) and not SSH (Port 22). You can read more about [the prerequisites here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html#rdp-prereqs).

When you created your Windows EC2 instance, you were asked to create a key. You can use this key to get the Windows password, assuming you used an AWS [AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html).

**Access your password**

Follow these steps (From the documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/retrieve-windows-admin-password/)):

- Open the Amazon EC2 console, and then choose Instances.
- Select the check box for the instance, and then expand the Actions dropdown list. If you're using the old console, then choose Get Windows Password. If you're using the new console, choose Security, and then choose Get Windows Password.
  **Note:** It can take a few minutes for this option to be available after you first launch a new instance.
- Choose Browse, select your key pair file, and then choose Open.

  -or-
- Paste the contents of your key pair into the text box.
  Choose Decrypt Password.

**Connect to the Instance**

On the password screen, Choose Download remote desktop file. Your browser prompts you to either open or save the RDP shortcut file. Select the option to save the file. When you have finished downloading the file, choose Cancel to return to the Instances page.

- Navigate to your downloads directory and open the RDP shortcut file.
- You might get a warning that the publisher of the remote connection is unknown. Choose Connect to continue to connect to your instance.
- The administrator account is chosen by default. Copy and paste the password that you saved previously.
- You can also use [EC2 Serial Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-serial-console.html) to access an EC2 instance running Windows, this is great to debug boot issues.
- Due to the nature of self-signed certificates, you might get a warning that the security certificate could not be authenticated. Use the following steps to verify the identity of the remote computer, or simply choose Yes (Windows) or Continue (Mac OS X) if you trust the certificate.

For more details on how to connect, visit this [site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html).

Comment: Also, after connecting to an instance, it is [possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) (at least in Windows Server 2019 base) to setup SSH, though it still asks you user's password

Comment: @OrkhanM., When you install the SSH from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse, How did you connect to the VM itself? Is there anything needed to be done on the AWS console?

Comment: @Royi I just posted [an alternate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75009915/8468492) with full steps for unattended SSH access.

Answer (score 5):

Late here but the answer is Yes you can SSH into a Windows EC2 instance from Windows/Linux and Mac(haven't tried).  The upshot is that you need an SSH server in order to receive ssh requests from clients.

1. Make sure your Windows instance is running
2. RDP into the instance (one-time only)
3. Type *powershell* in command line to toggle out of cmd
4. Run the following command to determine if you have OpenSSH.Server installed

> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

5. Install the service

> Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0

6. After a minute or two it installs (be patient)
7. Set service to start service automatically in case you stop instance

> Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'

8. Run the OpenSSH.Server service, called sshd

> Start-Service sshd

9. Exit the instance shell and RDP session
10. Go back to your shell on your computer
11. Run your customary ssh command to get into the EC2 instance.  You'll be prompted for a password. There are ways to get around that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, recent releases of Windows (10 build 1809, Server 2019, and later) offer official support for a native OpenSSH daemon. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell for details about OpenSSH on Windows.

When wanting to use SSH to connect to an EC2 instance specifically, I have found that the easiest approach is to build a new AMI with the OpenSSH package preinstalled and the relevant services preconfigured. The full process that is currently working for me:

1. Build a Windows AMI based on Server 2019 or later (e.g. use `Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-ECS_Optimized-2022.12.14` as the base AMI). As part of that AMI:

   1. Install OpenSSH and configure the `sshd` and `ssh-agent` services as described in the above link:

      ```bash
      $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

      Write-Host 'Installing and starting sshd'
      Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
      Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType Automatic
      Start-Service sshd

      Write-Host 'Installing and starting ssh-agent'
      Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
      Set-Service -Name ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
      Start-Service ssh-agent

      Write-Host 'Set PowerShell as the default SSH shell'
      New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value (Get-Command powershell.exe).Path -PropertyType String -Force
      ```
   2. Configure PowerShell as the default SSH shell:

      ```bash
      New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value (Get-Command powershell.exe).Path -PropertyType String -Force
      ```
2. Launch an EC2 instance using the new AMI:

   1. Provide a valid, existing SSH keypair.
   2. Select IMDSv2.
   3. Provide the following PowerShell script as the userdata script. This script will ensure the SSH keypair specified when launching will be added to the the `Administrator` user's authorized keys file. Note that the `<powershell>` and `</powershell>` tags *are* part of the userdata; they are parsed and extracted by AWS prior to the script being executed.

      ```bash
      <powershell>

      # Userdata script to enable SSH access as user Administrator via SSH keypair.
      # This assumes that
      # 1. the SSH service (sshd) has already been installed, configured, and started during AMI creation;
      # 2. a valid SSH key is selected when the EC2 instance is being launched; and
      # 3. IMDSv2 is selected when launching the EC2 instance.

      # Save the private key from instance metadata.
      $ImdsToken = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' -Method 'PUT' -Headers @{'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds' = 2160} -UseBasicParsing).Content
      $ImdsHeaders = @{'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token' = $ImdsToken}
      $AuthorizedKey = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-keys/0/openssh-key' -Headers $ImdsHeaders -UseBasicParsing).Content
      $AuthorizedKeysPath = 'C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys'
      New-Item -Path $AuthorizedKeysPath -ItemType File -Value $AuthorizedKey -Force

      # Set appropriate permissions on administrators_authorized_keys by copying them from an existing key.
      Get-ACL C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_dsa_key | Set-ACL $AuthorizedKeysPath

      # Ensure the SSH agent pulls in the new key.
      Set-Service -Name ssh-agent -StartupType "Automatic"
      Restart-Service -Name ssh-agent

      </powershell>
      ```
3. Connect to the instance via SSH like normal. Provide the SSH keypair you specified when launching and user `Administrator`. For example:

   ```bash
   ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-keypair Administrator@my.ec2.instance
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your Windows EC2 via `AWS Session Manager`.  It let you to manage your instance from browser based shell. Like SSH, you can manage your EC2 from the shell provided by the SSM. You can execute power shell commands from the console.

To use SSM, first you need to install ssm agent in instance and grant EC2 with required SSM policies in IAM role.

I believe SSM agent is by default installed in Windows EC2 instances. Also AWS providing one role named `AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup` for EC2. You can use the same or utilise the policies inside this role.

To connect: Select the instance and in the Connect option select Session manager

Answer (score 1):

PuTTy is not the tool to use typically for Windows machines.  While I'm sure it is possible to setup SSH access for Windows machines, the methods below are more typical and easier to setup.

If you have a keypair associated to your EC2 instance, you can use the AWS console to show you the username and password needed to use Windows Remote Desktop to access your machine by giving it your pem file.  This will also require you to enable inbound RDP access (a different port than SSH) in your security group.

If you just want PowerShell access and you are using an instance with with the SSM agent installed (e.g. Amazon Linux AMIs) and a role with the required SSM permissions, you can use Session Manager to connect.  This does not need a keypair or direct network access to your machine so this is a more secure method but requires a bit more setup.

Both techniques are described is more detail in the reference below.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html

Answer (score 1):

Can we SSH to Windows EC2 instance in AWS? - NO.

Windows EC2 you can connect using RDP( Remote Desktop ). You can download .rdp file from AWS console navigating through select instance -> connect -> RDP

SSH connection is for Linux based EC2 machine.