# Cant connect to Linux instance in AWS using SSH client

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, client, instance

I have downloaded the following private key from the AWS console to my C drive:  `cloud-labs-nv.pem`

I am trying to run the following command to connect to my Linux instance through SSH client and i get the following error:

```bash
> ssh -i "cloud-labs-nv.pem" ec2-user@ec2-3-83-91-162.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-user@ec2-3-83-91-162.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: Maybe try going through the comments in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74916444/problem-connecting-via-ssh-from-windows-to-aws-linux-instance-permission-denied/74919578?noredirect=1#comment132225417_74919578).

Comment: It is basically saying that the provided private key in the PEM file does not match a public key in the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. That was not the key that was provided when the instance was launched.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Andrew! When asking questions about error codes, try to put a short of the error code in the title: What does the error "amazonaws.com: Permission denied" mean? As you can see, a clear question sometimes answers itself. From there people can then help you understand how .ssh key work with Amazon or find links to tutorials to configure it.